# Suggestions for running more cables through (or around) top plate

Tags: code-compliance, ethernet, cable-management, relocating

I have a cabinet recessed into the wall of my garage where all of our TV, phone and ethernet cables come together and are terminated.  The house is 20 years old and had 2 Coax for DirecTV, an ethernet cable and a phone line run to pretty much every room.  So there are currently about 15-20 Coax cables and 15 Cat5e/Cat6 cables coming down through the double top plate of the wall where that cabinet is located.

I am going to install a new switch, router, modem etc. in the room above the garage and will need to run about 20 patch cables up from the punch down modules in the cabinet to the switch in that room.  Unfortunately, there isn't much room left to drill more holes in the top plate.  I came up with 3 routes that might work:

1. I could try and pull most of the Coax cable which is no longer being used back up through the top plate and use those holes.  This might be tough because I don't know if they are attached to the studs or how well the terminated ends will fit back through the holes.
2. I could disconnect the Ethernet cables that are coming from upstairs and send them back up and terminate them in a patch panel at the new location.  But there are only 10 cables coming down so I don't think that will give me the room I need for 20 patch cables.
3. I could come out of the wall with conduit and go up through the ceiling and bypass the top plate.  I'd prefer to keep everything hidden in the wall, but this may be my only option.

I thought I would check and see if anyone else had run into this issue of trying to get many wires down through a top plate before and if there is another option I haven't considered?  The garage has a storage truss roof and the wall in question is an interior wall (not at the outer edges of the trusses) so I don't believe it is load bearing.  Maybe that gives more flexibility in terms of more holes in the top plate?

Any help would really be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Any of those three methods are suitable for doing what you want. Which is "best" is a matter of opinion (especially since you haven't given us a criteria for defining what "best" is), and opinion based questions are off-topic. Please take the [tour] and browse the [Help], especially the part on asking questions to see how things work a little differently around here. Also, your question title really doesn't relate much to the situation at hand by asking a brief version of the question you're getting at in the body. Feel free to [edit] to improve your question!

Comment: Thanks for the comments!  I tried to clean it up a bit.

Comment: In general, more switches can help to mitigate the need for multiple long Enet cable runs.  Also, have you looked at going more wireless (WiFi), with perhaps a Wireless Access Point strategically located.  Finally, mesh WiFi systems can provide broad coverage with a minimum of cabling.

Comment: Aside: In the USA there are generally requirements that walls and ceilings between a dwelling and a garage meet fire resistance standards. Poking holes and running inappropriately rated cables may be frowned upon. Applicable codes in your location may vary.

Comment: *I have a cabinet recessed into the wall of my garage.* Remove. Install a cabinet *not* recessed into the wall there, with no back on it. Put the new stuff in it. Drink beer. - Or remove (an existing?) shelf in that cabinet which is preventing you from standing everything on its side. .... but yeah, mesh wifi, all day. New construction had better get cat5. But these days to retrofit it? nah

Answer (score 2):

You might consider trunking from the switch in the garage cabinet up to a switch in the room above the garage. So cat6 from the patch panel to the existing switch in the closet, then fiber from the trunk port up through the top plate to the room above and to the switch there, and then cat6 to the router, etc. Downsides are now you're talking 2 switches (which could get spendy) and a tiny bit more network latency.

Comment: Thanks for a great suggestion!  Unfortunately, the point of making this move is to get the switch out of that cabinet.  Garage gets pretty hot and I'm having problems with switches failing.  I can't go with a larger, more robust switch because there isn't room in the cabinet.